# How to close Android Studio using terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, terminal

I'm Ubuntu & Android beginner. I need help to close Android Studio using the terminal or a solution to resolve the error which is shown in this image:

[image: android_error]

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
pkill java
```

Is the easiest one.

**EDIT**

Many people have made use of the command above, however, there is a drawback to using it: All Java applications running as your user will be killed.

To fix this, I've made a oneliner which will kill one Android Studio instance. This may or may not work on your particular system but is a better solution than the one mentioned above if it happens to work for you.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd | grep -Ev "^ {0,1}([0-9]*) grep.*" | grep -E 'java.*android-studio' | sed -re 's/ {0,1}([0-9]*) .*/\1/' | head -n1 | xargs kill -9
```

This will search for `java.*android-studio` in the commands of your process list and kill the associated process using its PID.

Comment: Best One and +1

Comment: This works for me till date. But may be it's adaptable to it
kill -9 pid works for me

Comment: Wouldn't this also kill other running Java applications, too?

Comment: It would try to terminate other Java applications, but only the ones running as your user.

Answer (score 48):

```
killall -9 java
```

It works for me.

Comment: Wouldn't that kill any other java applications, too?

Comment: Yes, it will kill other java application too.

Answer (score 9):

2 steps are required:

1. Find the process id i.e **pid** of your running process (android-studio in your case) using the below command:

   ```
   % sudo su

   % ps -ef
   ```

By this, you will get the whole list of processes running into your 
Ubuntu, find the **pid** of your android studio.

2. Now kill the process using pid of android-studio:

   ```
   % kill -9 pid
   ```

Comment: It worked for me without sudo su as well

Answer (score 5):

You can try `xkill` command through terminal in Ubuntu,It will ask which window to close ,Your cursor becomes a cross-sign cursor and whichever window/application you will click with that cursor,it will kill it .this is applicable to any application/window in general .

Note: Never try to run this on desktop or sidebar or any system application ,otherwise it will kill it immediately and you may need to apply system restore so be careful .

Answer (score 2):

Can be used `pkill` or `killall` as per your `selection criteria` or `specified commands`

1. `pkill java`

`pkill` - looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout. All the criteria have to match. It will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout. ref. [pkill1](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) [pkill2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html)

2. `killall -9 java`

`killall` - sends a signal to all processes running any of the specified commands. If no signal name is specified, SIGTERM is sent. Signals can be specified either by name (e.g.  -HUP or -SIGHUP) or by number (e.g.  -1) or by option -s. If the command name is not regular expression (option -r) and contains a slash (/), processes executing that particular file will be selected for killing, independent of their name ref. [killall1](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) [killall2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following approach.
Use `ps aux` to list processes. Find the application we are looking for. In our example it is 'android-studio'.

[image: output of ps aux command]

From the screenshot we can see that there are 3 processes related to 'android-studio'. So in our example case, to kill the instance we could use either: `kill 10317` (PID of `studio.sh`) or `kill 10333` (PID of `jbr/bin/java`). I have not tried with the PID of `fsnotifier` so not sure if it would work.

NOTE: Use PIDs that you get as output from `ps aux` command, the numbers `10317` and `10333` are from my output screenshot for demonstration purposes.

This approach does not kill other java applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `pkill -f` is for. The *-f* switch matches a regular expression against the processes to terminate.

```
pkill -f '.+android-studio.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***pkill java*** to kill the android studio

and as for the error that is shown in the image it isnt clear what is but something that you are using in your java file happens to be null

try to post the whole error and the line where the exception is raised

Answer (score 0):

```bash
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep "Android Studio.app" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps -ef | grep android-studio` to get the running PID for android studio and then kill the PID with `kill PID` command

For example

```
// The below command is used to get the running PID for the Andriod studio app.
akshoy@victus:~$ ps -ef | grep android-studio
akshoy     37041    7278 59 23:09 ?        00:04:13 /snap/android-studio/148/jbr/bin/java -classpath /snap/android-studio/148/lib/app.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/3rd-party-rt.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/util.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/util_rt.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/util-8.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/jps-model.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/stats.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/protobuf.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/external-system-rt.jar:/snap/android-studio/148/lib/intellij-test-discovery.jar:/snap/android-studio/1
akshoy     39061   37041  0 23:09 ?        00:00:00 /snap/android-studio/148/bin/fsnotifier
akshoy     39114   37041  0 23:09 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash --rcfile /snap/android-studio/148/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in -i
akshoy     79463   54729  0 23:16 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto android-studio

// Running PID for android studio is 37041. So killing it below.
akshoy@victus:~$ kill 37041
```